# IP setting for client computers accessing internet via a firewall/router

Tags: ip, windows-sbs-2003, windows-firewall

I am a bit of a noob, I have a sbs server and client computers connected to a switch that is then connected to a firewall/router. The sbs server creates private ip address for the client computers, my question is when the client computers connect to the internet what ip address is seen and should it be translated to a public address or is there a setup step I am missing, can someone guide me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically (but not always), the IP that is displayed to remote stations is the primary IP of your firewall.  That is assuming it is a basically firewall/router appliance with a single IP doing NAT.  So outside of your facility, if one of your stations browses the internet, it will appear to come from the WAN IP assigned to your router.

you can check to see what the IP by visiting websites like www.whatismyip.com that report back your IP (www.Speedtest.net does as well).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is roughly what I thought but I read a book describing the client machines connecting to switch where a server is connected, as having public ips so it confused me a bit as to how it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: In the case of a LAN like you describe, the IPs might be static, or dynamically assigned by either the server (typical) or the router (typical in some setups).  Those IPs are typically part of a private pool that is not internet accessable.  I keep saying typically because there are so many configurations and ways of accomplishing network, that there is simply no "one" singluar  answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have 5 fixed IPs from my ISP and would like to access the servers remotely as web servers or ftp servers possibly for users.

Comment: your firewall will need to support being able to handle multiple WAN IPs.  If it can, you can map the ports in via the IPs using NAT rules.  But that is a VERY glossy overview of what is involved.  Please be sure to have an experienced IT person take a look.